# Mulesoft for-each inside scatter-gather

Tags: routes, foreach, mulesoft, mule4

Here I have a requirement where I need to process a single message into 2 different target systems. Hence I'm using scatter gather in mule.
Also, im handling the exceptions.

In each route of scatter gather - I need to process the messages inside foreach scope.

If error occurs in any routes for any element present outside foreach - `MULE:COMPOSITE_ROUTING` is giving me the proper errors(say 2 if both route fails)

But if error occurs inside the element present in foreach scope - then it is giving me only one route's error which is occurring at last.

I need to know how can I get both the route's error, what am I missing in configuring foreach or scatter-gather scope.

Comment: Provide the XML of the flow -as text- and examples of the errors. Which version and patch level are you using? What do you mean by the element inside the foreach?

Answer (score 0):

You will only get 1 error from `foreach` because `foreach` fails at the first error. i.e. if you have 5 elements, and the process inside the `foreach` fails with an `error` for the 3rd element, the 4th and 5th will not continue to process.

To get the `foreach` to continue processing, you will need to either use a [`parallel-foreach`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/latest/parallel-foreach-scope) or you will need to handle the errors using an `on-error-continue` within your `foreach` scope and then add validation or something to check if any element failed after the `foreach` completes